# saying about in which department people work

Tags: ellipsis

I have next statements about people's company's department:

> He **'s in production**. They make the company's products.
>
> She **'s in HR**. She finds new people to work for the company.

I think that we can say these sentences another way:

> He works in production and they make the company's products.
>
> She works in HR and finds new people to work for the company.

But can we say them in one more another way, maybe it's a bit silly question, but I'm completely not sure about it:

> He **'s in production** and **they make** the company's products.
>
> She **'s in HR** and **finds** new people to work for the company.

I ask because I'm not sure that it's correct to join two verbs - 'to be' and 'to do' to one object (he, she)?

And if the last two sentences above are correct do I need 'she' here?

> She's in HR and **she** finds new people to work for the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join two sentences with *and*, you should take care of parallelism. In other words, both the clauses should be grammatically same.

Having said this,

> He 's in production. They make the company's products - is fine because here, **they** refers to the production department/unit.
>
> He 's in production and they make the company's products - does not sound okay to me. 'They' could create an ambiguity *[singular they?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)* as the first pronoun was epicene. Here, *He's in production and **he** makes....* might fit better.

Now the other sentence,

> She 's in HR. She finds new people to work for the company - is okay because here it defines **what she does** in that department.
>
> She's in HR and finds new people to work for the company - does not sound okay to me. It does not fulfill the parallelism.

That's because...

> She **is** in HR. She **finds** ... so when you join them, the verb parallelism does not happen.

Had it been...

> She **works** in HR (dept). She **finds** new people for the company

It'd be possible to join *She's works in HR and finds...*

This means, you got it right...

> She's in HR and she finds new people to work for the company -is correct.

Comment: Please, could you define what you mean by "parallelism"? I'm finding difficult to follow the argument.

Comment: Is it correct to say: 'He works in the sales department and they have to meet their target each month.' ? Or I should split this sentence if I understand clearly your answer.

Comment: @Selio avoid ambiguity, split the sentence. *He works in the sales department that has to meet their monthly target.* Here, *that* will refer to the closest noun i.e. department.

Comment: @Nico even better is this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28grammar%29

Comment: @MaulikV I couldn't find *"verb parallelism"* in the wikipedia entry.

Comment: @MaulikV This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+*+and+finds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cis%20%2A%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20satisfied%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20encouraged%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20formed%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20hungry%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20well%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20married%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20released%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20lucky%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20successful%20and%20finds%3B%2Cc0) shows uses breaking"verb parallelism"

Comment: @Nico It was added to make the OP understand. There's no specific verb/adjective/adverb etc. parallelism. Parallelism is parallelism as I said and gave links.

Comment: "Maulik V Last question. Please, could you explain why texbook gives the sentence 'She works in accounts and deals with all our invoices.' ? They don't split it and even not add 'she' to the second part of the sentence.

Comment: @Selio Again, that's what I answered. *She **works** in accounts and **deals** with all our invoices* -check the parallelism - works & deals. It cannot go like *She **works** in accounts and **is** a beautiful girl!.* **'works' is not grammatically parallel to 'is'**